# How to store two integers in one array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to create an array that can store ID and Content in a single cell. I want to store the information so that I could receive both pieces of information from one piece of input.

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
int order[100];
int content[100];
int count = 0;

//method for adding a new piece of information
void setFrame(int nextOrder, int nextContent){
    order[count] = nextOrder;
    content[count] = nextContent;
    count++;
}
```

This works, but I would like a way to call a single array, like Array[i], and get two integers from it. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `struct`:

```
struct Data{
    int order;
    int content;
};

Data array[100];
int count = 0;

//method for adding a new piece of information
void setFrame(int nextOrder, int nextContent){
    array[count].order = nextOrder;
    array[count].content = nextContent;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use standard class `std::pair` declared in header `<utility>`

```
#include <utility>

//...

std::pair<int, int> order[100];

void setFrame( int nextOrder, int nextContent )
{
    order[count++] = { nextOrder, nextContent };
}
```

Comment: @AndreasVennström `std::pair` *is* a 2-element tuple.

Comment: @AndreasVennström: Lol what "scalability"? If you were to add another element, you'd need to change the type. And changing the type from `std::pair<int, int>` to `std::tuple<int, int, int>` is not more onerous than changing it from `std::tuple<int, int>` to `std::tuple<int, int, int>`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's fair, but I wouldn't expect OP to be able to figure that out, since he seems to be quite a newbie at the language.

Comment: @AndreasVennström: The OP didn't suggest it; you did. Or are you suggesting that we use `tuple` from the off to save the OP the trouble of figuring out how to migrate from `pair` to `tuple` in the future? That seems a little patronising?! lol